# Spring boot simple API mismatches HTTP requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have this extremely simple API in spring boot

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;


    @PostMapping()
    public UserModel createUser(@RequestBody UserModel user){
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public List<UserModel> getUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "{id}")
    public Optional<UserModel> getUserById(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/searchByName/{name}")
    public List<UserModel> requestMethodName(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        return userRepository.findByName(name);
    }

}
```

When I run, it compiles well and throws no error, but when I make get requests it mismatches the request as follows:

When I do: "http://localhost:2202/users" I get the list of all users without problems,

But when I call: "http://localhost:2202/users?id=5e6f5b4d19d83c38af6c648d" I still get the list of all users. When I place a breakpoint in the "getUserById" action of the controller, the breakpoint never hits.

Also, when I call: "http://localhost:2202/users/searchByName?name=Runtebala" I get a 400 Bad Request.

This is driving me crazy, does anyone have a solution? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update @GetMapping value for `getUserById` like this :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")  // add '/' before the parameter
public Optional<UserModel> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return userRepository.findById(id);
}
```

For `requestMethodName` you need to fix the request. Add '/' before name :

```
"http://localhost:2202/users/searchByName/Runtebala"
```

And update your method like this :

```
@GetMapping(value="/searchByName/{name}")
public List<UserModel> requestMethodName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
    return userRepository.findByName(name);
}
```

If you need to use @RequestParam don't specify the parameter in the Mapping value and just leave your method params with @RequestParam.

Hope it helps, Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

When deciding to add the id or any variable to the http request, you should also try using a notation called "@pathvariable" in this way:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Optional<UserModel> getUserById(@PathVariable String id) {
    return userRepository.findById(id);
}
```

If you choose to use @ RequestParam
Try the following:

```
@GetMapping("/searchByName/name")
public List<UserModel> requestMethodName(@RequestParam String name) {
    return userRepository.findByName(name);
}
```

Note that I did not use value =
Because I don't have to, but if you want to its great!
I don't know much about your software but note that your userRepository does return a list of UserModel
But I think the findByName  function in you software returns you one object, if you want to return a list you should create a service called findById on all of your UserModel and return an appropriate list.
If I did not understand the purpose of this function, please explain.